# Please don't say I approved an edit if I didn't

Tags: feature-request, bug, 10k-tools

I just saw this on the `/tools/suggested-edits` page:

[image]

But, I didn't approve that edit:

[image]

Please only show my name if I approved it.

This review is from the [elementary OS private beta](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 7):

Yep, that is definitely a bug since you rejected it in the first place.

It seems to add the names of who reviewed the tag wiki edit to the "Approved by:" or "Rejected by:". I suppose the system should be changed so it adds the names who actually approved it instead. Or it might as well add, "Reviewed by:" and if you hover over the names of the users, a tooltip will be there saying "Approved" or "Rejected".